# ldap query with wildcard

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have a query like below

```
(|(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_CHARGE_BACK,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com)(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_Compliance,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com)(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_Finance,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com)(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_GP,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com)(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_MANAGED_CARE,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com)(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_MEDICAID,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com)(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_PowerUser,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com)(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_TRADE,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com)(distinguishedName=cn=Game_BI_TRICARE,ou=Groups,ou=FC,dc=na,dc=company,dc=com))
```

I want to shorten it using wildcard, All the group names start with Game_BI. The above query works, I just want to make it short.

Thanks
Shashi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the wildcard `*` character to filter the `distinguishedName` attribute - only exact matches will work. You can read more about that here, under the LDAP Clauses section :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx

However, according to your current filter, you could do a wildcard search by canonical name, or `cn`, and get the same result :

`(&(objectClass=group)(cn=Game_BI*))`

That says, "Give me all the groups that have a canonical name that begins with "Game_BI".