# How to search Active Directory users by their domain name?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using this code to retrieve all users from my Windows domain:

```
string domainName = null; // search by current domain
string ldapFilter = $"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";
string[] propsToLoad = null; // load all ad properties

using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(domainName))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry, ldapFilter, propsToLoad, SearchScope.Subtree))
    {
        using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult searchItem in results.OfType<SearchResult>())
            {
                ResultPropertyCollection props = searchItem.Properties;

                foreach (string strProperty in props.PropertyNames)
                {
                    var enumerator = props[strProperty].GetEnumerator();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Property name: '{strProperty}'");

                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        string item = enumerator.Current.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine($"- '{item}'");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can specify `domainName` in `DirectoryEntry`, but I want to specify 
**domainName** in search criteria.

**EDIT**

Thanks for pointing out that wildcard can't be used with distinguishedName.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ldap query with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829104/ldap-query-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are searching a Global Catalog, since that's the only way you'd get results from more than one domain.

Your options are limited. If the users on each domain have a `userPrincipalName` unique to the domain, you can search by that:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=*@example.com))
```

But that's not necessarily the case. In our environment, everyone across all of our domains has the same domain in the `userPrincipalName`.

But that's the only way you can do it. There is no other attribute that you can use a wildcard on that can identify the domain.

If you are searching for a limited number of users, you could filter by the `distinguishedName` *after* you get the results. But you wouldn't want to do that if you're searching for *every* account on the domain.

If you're more specific about what you are trying to do, I might be able to offer a better suggestion.

Comment: I'll post here an example. When I retrieve all users from ad one of the result is: `givenName=Mike`, `sn=Posner`, `distinguishedName CN=Mike Posner,OU=Users,OU=X Plus,OU=Company,DC=MyDomainName,DC=xplus,DC=local`, `userPrincipalName=mikep@companyName.com`. Like you suggested it would be find, if the domain name (xplus) would be in `userPrincipalName`, but it's not.

Comment: Funny though I get as response for each user next two attributes: `adsPath="LDAP://CN=Mike Posner,OU=Users,OU=XPlus,OU=Company,DC=MyDomainName,DC=xplus,DC=local"` and `msDS-PrincipalName=mikep\myDomainName`. But can't search by attribute `adsPath`.

Comment: `aDSPath` is just the path used to bind to the object. It's usually the `distinguishedName` with `LDAP://` in front (but it could be different, depending on how you connected to it). `msDS-PrincipalName` is a constructed attribute: it's calculated at the time you ask for it, so you can't use it in a search.

Comment: But really, if you know the domain you want results from, why can't you just search only that domain?

Comment: I pass `null` for domain, therefore I get all users from current or multiple domains. I'm not sure about multiple domains as I'm testing only in our environment. The reason I need to search by domain is because the user can filter users by domain. Just image list view with items like this: MyDomain\Mikep, MyDomain\User1 ..... I want to do server filtering and not client. Client filtering solves the problem, but when users count is more than 50k it gets slow. Therefore I would like server filtering.

Comment: Why can't I search by domain name: MyDomainName\Mikep is the attribute value which is returned from the search. The result includes domain name, but can't search by result value. It's funny.

Comment: If you're passing `null` for the domain, then it is searching the domain you're logged into, and *only* that one domain. So there's no reason to need filtering by domain. The only way you can get results from multiple domains is if you specifically connect to the Global Catalog, which will get you results from your whole AD forest. You do that by specifying the GC port: `new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com:3268")`